# Hey diddle diddle, the big cat in the riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, story, geography

Okay I've written a bad rhyming story that is mostly fluff, but hidden in this story there are two(2) things that symbolise a place on Earth. One thing symbolises a Country whilst the other a City within that country. Can you find out where? And tell me why?

> We start our story on the safari,
>   Looking out at the night sky, so starry!
>   There were lots of strange sounds coming from the bush,
>   Stopping me from sleeping, I wanted to yell "Shush!"
>
> Eventually I was so tired that I fell asleep,
>   All I had to do was count some sheep.
>   In the next morning I woke with a start,
>   What I saw made me eek out a small fart.
>
> Right in my face was a great bloody maw,
>   I could tell by the mane it was a lion that I saw.
>   But instead of swallowing me in one big bite,
>   It was nudging me awake to show me its plight.
>
> Along the lion's back was a great big slash,
>   All gooey and pussy, it was an infected gash.
>   I noticed there were two other lions nearby,
>   With similar wounds all covered in flies.
>
> I led the lions to a nearby waterhole,
>   And cleaned their cuts using a wooden bowl.
>   Once they were washed, the lions seemed happy.
>   I was just glad to not have found anything snappy.

Comment: I love the premise of this riddle, and I like how it is known that most of it is fluff. It makes it very distinct from most other riddles, where you know that every line contains at least one hint. Now you never know what could be a hint and what not! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the country is probably

> England, symbolised by "Three Lions", which appear on the English coat of arms.

Less sure about the city, perhaps it is

> Bath, as in the lions are given a bath in the waterhole?

Comment: This is correct! Well done for sorting the wheat from the chaff :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the country is

> England, whose symbol is three lions.

The city

> has to have something to do with the lions' scars. Maybe Scarborough?

Comment: Nice idea, but I think the location you suggest is a town rather than a city.

Comment: The country is correct, but your city is not, good try :D